# Why text loader from langchain is not working

Tags: javascript, next.js, langchain

I struggle through the solution provided online yet cannot figure out why I got the error below even I ensure I install the textloader module correctly and the file I'm reading is a text file named smearing.txt.

The error message is

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: readFile is not a function which happen 
at textloader.load
```

Attached also my next.config.mjs file

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    experimental:{serverComponentsExternalPackages:['faiss-node']},
    reactStrictMode: true,
    swcMinify: true,
    webpack: (config, { webpack }) => {
      config.experiments = { ...config.experiments, topLevelAwait: true };
      config.externals["node:fs"] = "commonjs node:fs";
      config.resolve.fallback = {
      ...config.resolve.fallback,
      fs: false,
   };
      config.plugins.push(

        new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
          /^node:/,
          (resource) => {
            resource.request = resource.request.replace(/^node:/, '');
          },
        ),
      );
      return config;
    }
  }

export default nextConfig;

"use client";
import { OpenAI } from "@langchain/openai";

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import classes from "./chat.module.css";
import { RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter } from "langchain/text_splitter";
import { TextLoader } from "langchain/document_loaders/fs/text";
import { OpenAIEmbeddings } from "@langchain/openai";
import { FaissStore } from "@langchain/community/vectorstores/faiss";

export default function Chatbox() {
  const [res, UpdateRes] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("run");
    let data: any;
    const model = new OpenAI({
      openAIApiKey: MY_API_KEY,
      temperature: 0,
    });
    const loader = new TextLoader("./smearing.txt");
    const docs = await loader.load();
```

Comment: Sounds similar to [Unable to read text data file using TextLoader from langchain.document_loaders library because of encoding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76600384/205233)